# Exporting high quality jpeg in illustrator & keeping dimensions. Options

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, export

I'm exporting a jpeg in illustrator for Society6 and they want maximum quality at specific dimensions. As I understand it, the only way to keep the high resolution with the same printed output I should take it into photoshop at resize the image back down. I was told to uncheck "resample Image" in the dialog box before clicking okay but the image then reverts back to the old size. What am I missing here? I'm so lost right now :)

Or is there a simple way around all of this without having to take it into multiple programs?

I've also used "save to web" in Illustrator, but even at high quality the image is not as crisp as it is when I export. I just want to make sure my image is quality before posting on society6 as it will be used for print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your export image a specific dimension make a new artboard for that size and duplicate your art to it. Then, when you export your image just make sure 'Use Artboards' is checked at the bottom of the window and then have your settings like the image below.

[image]

**Then you will need to go into Photoshop and size it down from 5417 x 8333 to 1300 x 2000. Keep ppi at 300, and you'll be good to go.**

[image]

Comment: Thank you I will try that again... I have done it before, and it seems to still output larger than the 1300x2000px dimensions that I need. My issue is when going into photoshop and scale down my image, I wasn't sure if I should unclick image resampling because it seems when I do I am unable to make it smaller. I also was unsure, if saving to web while in illustrator at highest quality, if it diminishes the clarity of the output image especially for print on Society6.

Comment: 1300x2000px at what ppi? - If you do Save for web, it's going to force 72ppi

Comment: Ah, so that makes sense then. Saving to web even at the maximum quality will still be 72 ppi? So it's essentially the same as exporting at 72ppi. I guess I was only seeing the difference when exporting at 300ppi it would make sense that would be clearer, and bigger. I was told that for print saving to web at highest quality is still efficient for society6, however it doesn't feel that way and I would hate to have something for sale that isn't clear. I'm just a little lost as to what everyone else does to stay within specific dimensions while maintaining a sharp image.

Comment: Yes, see my updated answer with a new screenshot

Comment: Okay, Thank you so much! So keep resample checked then correct? Thanks, this is helpful. Why on earth something so simple has taken me forever to wrap my head around :-)

Comment: No problem, if this answered your question you can mark it as such or upvote it from 0. Good luck on Society6!

Answer (score 1):

You simply create your artboard the size needed (plus any bleed if needed for print) - This will generate the size you need. Then when you export (JPEG I assume?) you simply choose CMYK color mode (hopefully you were already in CMYK) quality at maximum, and resolution minimum 300 PPI for print. Personally, I like 600. But there is NO need to goto Photoshop and resize anything... you are just asking for problems. Also uncheck the ICC profile, unless you want your colors to shift on the exported file.

Now let's say you are printing large format vinyl banners... then 300 is overkill, and you would need 150 and full scale, or 300 at half scale etc

(20+ years printing experience)